# When I click on Parent Category, there are no products displayed

Tags: category

I have **three level category** structure.

I do not see any **products** until I click **on the last category**.

Can I have sub category products displayed on the parent category page too?

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

yes possible.

You need to enable

[image]